# How can I implement explosion effects in a 3D game?

Tags: graphic-effects

I was wondering how I could implement explosion effects in a 3D game. I'm specifically interested in graphical techniques for creating the effects, not the related logic or systems.

Comment: It depends on the game, and the explosion. A VFX artist will use different techniques depending on the effect they want to achieve. Can you clarify your question to something along the lines of... "I'm making [this kind of game]. So far I'm doing my explosions [this way] and I want my explosions to look like or function like [this - include detailed description or example images/animations]. How can I achieve this effect?" - that will help us narrow in on specific answers that are useful to you.

Comment: I'm making an open world FPS. I am now working with sprites for making explosives. I like to have some physical elements in my explosion like fragmentation into the character. This way damage dealing will also be for objects, enemies and companions (without actually adding more lines of code in any of the characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many particles which is actually sprites (So, yes. It is sprites). You might want to see [this](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/creative/visual-arts/make-a-particle-explosion-effect-r2701). It has images that might make you understand how it works.

Though i recall there's also volumetric effects for clouds/mist like in [Sonic Ether's](https://www.facebook.com/SonicEther/?fref=ts) mod (The clouds is volumetric and the light too). And also, there's [this](https://stevencraeynest.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/easy-volumetric-explosion-in-unity3d/) volumetric explosion in unity, but i don't think that's a true volumetric because i feel like it is using trick to achieve the illusion of volume.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm sorry for my late response but I didn't receive any mail about this topic. Very clear information, But I am not working with Unity but Leadwerks, So I'm very dependent to standard techniques and such